# What is the best way to restrict page redirects when previous page is of a different hostname?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on one angular SPA. I have come across one scenario where I need to either restrict going back to previous page or manipulate the same.

Scenario 1:

```
URL 1: Landing page
    www.myapp.com/citizen/#/wizard/introduction

URL 2: User goes to login page
    www.myapp.com/citizen/#/wizard/login

URL 3: Login button redirect to third party service
    www.thirdpartylogin.com/login

URL 4: After successful login it redirects to 
    www.myapp.com/citizen/#/wizard/home
```

When user now clicks the back button I don't want user to go to URL 3. User should remain on URL 4 or even its fine if I take user to URL 3 or URL 2.

Scenario 2:

```
URL 1: Home page
    www.myapp.com/citizen/#/wizard/home

URL 2: User goes to third party payment page
    www.thirdpartypayment.com/payment

URL 3: Finish
    www.myapp.com/citizen/#/wizard/finish
```

In this scenario I don't want user to go to payment page and stay on URL 3 itself.

Is there any way to restrict or manipulate browser back button for both scenario 1 and scenario 2?

Comment: You could do some checking with cookies?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it by adding a step after landing from the third party service:

```
URL 3: Login button redirect to third party service
  www.thirdpartylogin.com/login

URL 3.5: This page redirects you to the next one
  www.myapp.com/citizen/#/wizard/haslogged

URL 4: After successful login it redirects to 
  www.myapp.com/citizen/#/wizard/home
```

In this way every time you go back form url 4 you will be redirected to url 4 itself. If you want to change behaviour, you could use [history.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) in url 3.5 before redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by disable browser back button

On Page Load:

```
  function disableBack() { 
        window.history.forward();
  }

   window.onload = disableBack();
```

---

On Page load:

```
history.pushState(null, null, 'pagename');

  window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
      history.pushState(null, null, 'pagename');
  });
```

Reference Link:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate

Answer (score 0):

### Changing the third party redirection

If you can control how the redirection from the third party to your app is done you can change it so it uses javascript to do the redirection :

```
window.location.replace(newLocation);
```

It will replace the current location with the new location in the back history.

### Using iframes

In most cases you won't have access to the service source code (unless you developed it yourself), so you'll have to create a page where you display the third party service in an iframe.

```
URL 1: Landing page
    www.myapp.com/citizen/#/wizard/introduction

URL 2: User goes to login page
    www.myapp.com/citizen/#/wizard/login

URL 2bis: Login button displays the third party service in an iframe (user is still on your application)
```

Now you want to know when the location inside the iframe changed (i.e when the login/payment is complete and the service redirects to your app). To do this with angular you'll need to create a simple directive that watch the load event on the iframe :

```
APP.directive('iframeOnload', [function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            callBack: '&iframeOnload'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.on('load', function(){
                return scope.callBack();
            })
        }
    }}])
```

And use it like this :

```
<iframe class="gds-taskform-iframe" height="1000" width="100%" iframe-on-load="myRedirect()" ng-src="{{ serviceUrl }}"></iframe>
```

Here is the controller code

```
APP.controller('testController', function ($sce, $scope, $location){
        var firstLoad = true;
        $scope.serviceUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://www.univ-smb.fr/");

        $scope.myRedirect = function(){
            if(!firstLoad){
                window.location.replace('http://google.com');
            }
            firstLoad = false;
        };
    });
```

Note that I use a boolean to check if this is the first load event of the iframe. If I don't it'll fire the redirection when the thrid party service loads for the first time.

Here is the full working code

```
<!Doctype html>
<html ng-app="test">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <!-- angular -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="testController">
            <iframe height="1000" width="100%" iframe-onload="myRedirect()" ng-src="{{ serviceUrl }}"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var APP = angular.module('test', []);

        APP.directive('iframeOnload', [function(){
        return {
            scope: {
                callBack: '&iframeOnload'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                element.on('load', function(){
                    return scope.callBack();
                })
            }
        }}])

        APP.controller('testController', function ($sce, $scope, $location){
            var firstLoad = true;
            $scope.serviceUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://www.univ-smb.fr/");

            $scope.myRedirect = function(){
                if(!firstLoad){
                    window.location.replace('http://google.com');
                }
                firstLoad = false;
            };
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Note you can run into *Refused to display 'http://serviceurl/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'* if the service's author do not want you to use it inside an iframe.